# opencv_traincascade.Unspecified error (No element name has been given)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to train my own cascade, but get the following error:

```
Unspecified error (No element name has been given) in cv::operator
 <<, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\core\include\
opencv2/core/operations.hpp, line 2910
```

I made ​​these steps:

1. I cut 20 photos of the object so that they remained only the desired object
2. Resize to 30x18
3. Make objectSamples.dat file like this :

> object(1).jpg 1 0 0 30 18
>
> object(10).jpg 1 0 0 30 18
>
> object(11).jpg 1 0 0 30 18

And negatives.dat like  :

```
negatives\1.jpeg
negatives\10.jpg
negatives\11.jpg
size of pic ~ 500x500
```

4.Make vec file:
*opencv_createsamples -info objectSamples.dat -vec objectSamples.vec -w 30 -h 18 -num 20*

5.Show samples ( my pictures are shown entirely) : *opencv_createsamples  -vec objectSamples.vec -w 30 -h 18*

6.Try to train : *opencv_traincascade -data Cascade -vec objectSamples.vec -bg negatives.dat -numPos 10 -numNeg 10 -numStages 2 -featureType HAAR -w 30 -h 18*

But get an error:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

I read these articles and the answer, but I didn't understand, in what a problem:

1. [trouble-when-use-opencv_traincascadeexe](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8891/trouble-when-use-opencv_traincascadeexe/)
2. [haartraining tutorial](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#Tutorial)
3. [docs.opencv traincascade](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html?highlight=train%20cascade#cascade-training)

---

Increased the number of images to 1000 positive and 2000 negatives

```
opencv_traincascade -data Cascade -vec boobsSamples.vec -bg negativesBig/negatives.txt -numPos 400 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 2 -featureType HAAR -w 30 -h 18 -mode ALL
```

Geting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

I copied the opencv_traincascade.exe to a folder of images. When I ordered the full path to the opencv_traincascade.exe in the library, the problem disappeared.

```
F:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_traincascade -data Cascade -vec positives.vec -bg negativesBig/negatives.txt -numPos 400 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 2 -featureType HAAR -w 30 -h 18 -mode ALL
```